# C behavior (non initialized values)

Tags: c

I had a question regarding a C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void){
        int a;
        printf("%d\n",a);
}

void bar(void){
        int a = 42;
}

int main(void){
        bar();foo();
}
```

Apparently I am supposed to get a 42 as a result at the end of compilation.  http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c  , slide #126. But when I compile it on my machine I get garbage values `(gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5))`

Do I need to turn off some optimization? Or is the author of the slide wrong about this? Can someone explain what should be the result of the code? If it is 42, could you also explain how/why? Also, would the result be any different on a C++ compiler (g++).

Comment: Slides 137 and 138 explain this. Just keep reading. The author of the slide is talking about behavior he observed under specific conditions. He is not claiming that any of this is guaranteed to happen. (And, by the way, if you don't already have a solid understanding of what undefined behavior *is*, learning about the specifics of particular cases can actually do you more harm than good. You must already understand that you can *never* rely on it.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz True, but as I mentioned in my question, is there a way to turn off these optimization?

Comment: There is no way to get this kind of undefined behavior to be guaranteed to come out a particular way. That's what makes it undefined. Some flags might happen to do what you are asking for, maybe '-O0', maybe not. The whole point is that the behavior is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing uninitialized variables is simply undefined behavior.
Undefined behavior means that the standard doesn't specify how to behave in some situations, including this one. The compiler might even "make demons fly out of your nose" (popular joke about UB :) )

In that article the program works because `bar`'s `a` and `foo`'s `a` are placed in the same memory location, but this is completely uninsured and you should ***never rely on such behaviors!***

Answer (score 3):

There is no knowing what you will get.  The assumption I guess is that the second stack frame will be in the same location as the last and as the var a is the first variable it should be assigned the same location as the a from the previous functions stackframe.  But that is not defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Things that you can try to obtain the desired result (the value propagating from `bar` to `foo`):

- Maybe the variable `a` is allocated in CPU registers and not in stack. In order to force allocation on stack, try using its address (`&a`) in some way.
- Maybe the compiler generates some code to stuff the uninitialized variables on stack with a debugging pattern (`0xcdcdcdcd`) - i think gcc doesn't do it but maybe i am wrong?
- Examine the machine code generated by the compiler - this is the ultimate way

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function, the CPU first pushes the function arguments on the stack, pushes the return address on the stack and then proceeds to jump to the function's code.
There, it saves the old stack position by pushing it on the stack (function prologue).
Next, it allocates the *a* variable on the stack (again) and sets it's value to 42.

While exiting the function (function epilogue), the CPU removes the *a* variable from the stack **by just moving the stack pointer back** to where it saved the old stack position and gets that old position. The **value 42 stored at that place in the memory is kept intact**!

Then, the second function gets called and the same process takes place:

- push arguments (we skip this step since there are none)
- push return address (at the same place in memory that the other function's return address was stored)
- push stack position (same as with return address)
- allocate the *a* variable which ends in the exact same place in memory as the *a* variable from the bar() function!

Since bar's *a* variable was initialized to 42, that value is still there and foo's *a* "inherits" it by pointing to the same place in memory.

Stack before calling bar():

```
[someThings]<=StackPointer
```

Stack while in bar():

```
[someThings][returnAddress][oldStackPointer][a = 42]<=StackPointer
```

Stack after bar() and before foo():

```
[someThings]<-StackPointer {oldStackPointer}{a = 42}
```

Stack while in foo():

```
[someThings][newRetAddress][oldStackPointer][a (= 42 as the value was here before)]<=StackPointer
```

So, yes, the author of the slides is right and the ones saying he is wrong are in fact wrong themselves :)
(take note that it is important that the code is compiled without optimization)

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, this is undefined behaviour.

However, the author is partly right, on some architectures the address of the local variables will be the same, so `foo` will read the data that `bar` left there.

```
# gcc x.c; ./a.out
42
```

It's an interesting way to show what goes behind the scenes, but do not depend on it, it's architecture, compiler and optimization dependent:

```
# gcc -O2 x.c; ./a.out
0
```

BTW, if you read the next slides you'll get all the answers...

Comment: is there a way to force my compiler to behave in the way the author's compiler does?

Comment: turn off all optimizations. if that doesn't help, then, (probably) no... and doesn't matter, nobody will ever need it. you can't reproduce it.. so what? doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The author of that code is making a *lot* of platform-specific assumptions that simply don't hold in general.  He's assuming that local variables are stored in memory in a specific way, and that those locations won't be overwritten between function calls.  In general, he is wrong.

This is a textbook example *undefined behavior* - it's bad code, and the language standard places no requirements on the compiler to do anything specific with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two 'a' variables are local to function they're contained inside. The memory space occupied by the 'a' in foo() is not the same memory space as the 'a' in bar. So when you initialize the 'a' in bar, that 42 is thrown away when the function returns, and never ever affects the a in foo.

Answer (score 0):

**Since you're accessing an uninitialized variable, the behaviour of your code is undefined.**

Having said that, the program is quite likely to print 42 on architectures that I am familiar with. However, it would be outright silly to rely on this, even if the program were to behave this way on your architecture.

If anything, this behaviour might even be a hindrance, as getting consistent values from an uninitialized variables could mask bugs.